# Can I removeWhile from a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: scala

How do I remove the oldest entries from a `LinkedHashMap` without traversing the whole map or collecting keys in an intermediate collection? `LinkedHashMap` entries are sorted by insertion order, so the oldest are found first when iterating. I'd like to do this:

```
  userAndWhenMap.iterator.removeWhile { case (userId, userAndWhen) =>
    now.millisSince(userAndWhen.when) > DeleteAfterInactiveMillis
  }
```

But `removeWhile` doesn't exist. There's a `dropWhile` but it doesn't mutate the map — it advances an iterator. Is there no way to achieve something like `removeWhile`?

(I know about `retain` but it traverses the whole map. And I know I can find the keys I want to remove and insert them in a set and then loop through it and `Map.remove(..)`.)

Comment: I think the only option is to implement your `removeWhile` method as an extension for `LinkedHashMap` class, you can do this by just iterating while predicate holds and removing with `-=` as there are only two methods that modify the collection instead of returning new (retain and transform, I am ignoring ++=, +=, --= and -= here)

Comment: @Łukasz thanks. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it as the solution, after a day or two (unless someone else posts something that I'll accept instead :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to implement your removeWhile method as an extension method for `LinkedHashMap` class

There are only two methods that modify the this collection instead of returning new: `retain` and `transform` (I am ignoring ++=, +=, --= and -= here) and they don't do what you need.

here is example code:

```
implicit class LinkedHashMapOps[A, B](val self: LinkedHashMap[A, B]) extends AnyVal {
  def removeWhile(predicate: ((A, B)) => Boolean): self.type = {
    val toRemove = self.iterator.takeWhile(predicate).map(_._1)
    toRemove foreach (self -= _)
    self
  }
}
```

and test:

```
@ val map = new LinkedHashMap[Int, String]
@ map += (1 -> "a")
@ map += (2 -> "a")
@ map += (3 -> "a")
@ map += (4 -> "a")
res6: LinkedHashMap[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "a", 3 -> "a", 4 -> "a")
@ map.removeWhile(_._1 < 3)
res8: LinkedHashMap[Int, String] = Map(3 -> "a", 4 -> "a")
```